# FPDF - Centering text, Line height

Tags: php, html, fpdf

I am using [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) to draw some text in a PDF. I have implemented this [super cool extension class](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script42.php) to parse basic HTML into the PDF, but unlike `cell` and `multicell` there are no parameters for text alignment and height.

How can I change the text to center align and the line height with `$pdf->WriteHTML($text);`??

Comment: This is actually true about the base PDF framework/language. There isn't the idea of "centering", you simply know the length of your string and take half and set the margin to be that minus half the page width. very annoying.

Comment: But it's a multiline string. Before the need for HTML arose I used multicell, which has a parameter to center the text. This leads me to believe there must be a way to do it.. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this upgraded extension for WriteHTML with text alignment: http://fpdf.de/downloads/addons/41/.

Example (from the link):

```
<?php
define('FPDF_FONTPATH', 'font/');
require('WriteHTML.php');

$pdf=new PDF_HTML();
$pdf->Open();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial');
$pdf->WriteHTML('You can<BR><P ALIGN="center">center a line</P>and add a horizontal         rule <BR><HR>');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```